# Error assigining a structure array containing another structure array

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

This is my code:

```
struct first
{
    char x;
    int y;
};
first a[3]={{'a',1},{'c',2},{'b',3}};
struct second
{
    first b[2]; 
    int z;
};
second c={{a[0],a[1]},12};
```

Basically, when I'm assigning the `second` structure, the first element is supposed to be an array of the `first` structure type. So I am trying to put two elements `a[0]` and `a[1]` in it. But it shows the error:

`ERROR CYAPA.CPP 12: Cannot convert 'first' to 'char'`

`ERROR CYAPA.CPP 12: Cannot convert 'first' to 'int'`

What am I doing wrong? I am using Turbo c++ as it is what is allowed by our curriculum in India.

Comment: On gcc 4.8, the code compiled (I puh both initializations inside main()).

Comment: lol. You're _required_ to use Turbo C++. What a shame. :(

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ultimately ended up creating an 'id' for each element of the first structure, and just use an integer in the second structure to access a particular index of `a[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of initialization is not allowed in C, but it was allowed in C++98 .

Your compiler predates 1998 by several years so it is not surprising that it does not allow some things that did become part of the C++ Standard.

You'll have to write `{'a', 1}` instead of `a[0]` etc. , or use a macro. The macro solution might look like:

```
#define A0 {'a', 1}
#define A1 {'c', 2}
#define A2 {'b', 3}

first a[3]={A0, A1, A2};
second c={{A0, A1}, 12 };
```

Alternatively you could initialize `a` and then set up `c` at runtime.

Comment: Sad that my school uses such ancient standards... I'll definitely ask our Teacher to upgrade!